# Stella SDK to convert IOS App to Android

Tags: android, ios, sdk

I installed `Stella SDK` and tried to convert a demo iOS app `GLSprite` to android. Followed the steps, but it seems the big problem with the instructions is that everything is installed in the /opt folder on mac and that folder seems to be protected on my computer, so all the commands I have to use sudo which confuses everything.

Then when I use `Xcode` to open the `GLSprite` project, `xcode` has problems because of the permissions because the project is rooted in /opt on the mac.

So I moved the project to my home folder, then I get errors saying missing include files like GL.H

I followed the steps I found on this site (someone else asked the same question) but that didnt help, still cant find GL.H nd some other includes.

I was going to use apportable, but it seems they dont have `UIKit` implemented yet which my app uses a lot.

Has anyone used `Stella SDK` to convert `iOS` app to Android?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your original question - Stella requires using sudo and installing at /opt. Its tools depend upon hard coded paths.

The current `Apportable` UIKit implementation is already more complete than the one in `Stella SDK`.

A pre-release of a more complete Apportable UIKit implementation was made available yesterday. See this Ian Fischer's post in this [Apportable discuss thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/apportable-discuss/7O3LXc1jcq4) for details.